# Scrapy: not iterating over pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

class Litspider2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "litspider2"
    allowed_domains = ["https://ilibrary.ru"]
    start_urls = ["https://ilibrary.ru/text/94/p.1"]

    def parse(self, response):            

        yield {"url" : urlsplit(response.url)[2],
               "teil" : response.xpath("//h2/text()").get(),
               "kapitell" : response.xpath("//h3/text()").get(),
                "text" : " ".join(response.css("span.p::text").getall()).strip("'").strip(",").strip(" ").replace("\x97", "—")
        }
            
        next_chapter = response.css("[title='Дальше'] ::attr(href)").get()

        if next_chapter is not None:
            next_chapter_url = "https://ilibrary.ru" + next_chapter
            yield response.follow(next_chapter_url, callback=self.parse)
```

When crawling, Python ignores the callback to `self.parse` and prints only the first page. I don't get what is the error here. Perhaps, the main cause lies in the url format (`/index.html` is followed by the page number)?

Since I am new to Scrapy, I tried everything from soup to nuts, even though I used almost the same spider code before which went fine. What I changed is mainly the URLs in the code. I checked using different `start_urls` and the like.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you add your code's output?

Comment: My code ends with "до конца предстоявшего ему пути выходило версты три, и он решился взять извозчика.", which is the last sentence of the first chapter. The third line has no content.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  But the issue isn't with the url format its in your allowed domains.

According to the [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.Spider.allowed_domains)

> allowed_domains¶
>
> An optional list of strings containing domains that this spider is allowed to crawl. Requests for URLs not belonging to the domain names specified in this list (or their subdomains) won’t be followed if OffsiteMiddleware is enabled.
>
> Let’s say your target url is https://www.example.com/1.html, then add 'example.com' to the list.

Unfortunately you have a full `url` with the http scheme and all in your allowed domains which is throwing a parsing error.  The issue is hinted in the output for the crawl in the debug log for the offsite middleware like this:

```
2023-08-27 23:10:26 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ilibrary.ru': <GET https://ilibrary.ru/text/94/p.2/index.html>
```

All you need to do to correct the issue is change `'https://ilibrary.ru'` to `'ilibrary.ru'` in your `allowed_domains` list and it will solve your problem.

Example:

```
class Litspider2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "litspider2"
    allowed_domains = ["ilibrary.ru"]
    start_urls = ["https://ilibrary.ru/text/94/p.1"]
```